# How do i use redirectTo with an url containing a parameter?

Tags: angular, routes, angular9

I wish to redirect the user to the relative path `':lang/home'` when the path is `''`. However the `HomeComponent` will not load when I navigate to `localhost:4200/`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: ':lang/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

This only works when i replace `:lang` with a hardcoded language code like `en/home`.
I've tried `localhost:4200/:lang/home` and `/:lang/home` but that doesn't work either.
Both give the browser error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot redirect to '/:lang/home'. Cannot find ':lang'.
Error: Cannot redirect to '/:lang/home'. Cannot find ':lang'.
    at ApplyRedirects.findPosParam
```

How do i fix this? Thank you

Comment: :lang is a route param , its designed to replace the :lang with a route param you give in the route. localhost:4200/:lang/home is not a valid route

Comment: @MohitHarshan I know, but lets say a french user is using the website in french. In such a case he should always be redirected to `fr/home`, not to `en/home`. So how do i let the redirectTo option redirect to the correct relative path?

Comment: ok then Auth guard will be a solution

Comment: Make an authguard and inject router . Decide the logic in this Guard

Comment: ok, but are you saying that i cannot use url parameters  with `redirectTo` ?

Comment: then you have to decide the logic and set it to a variable when setting the routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an Route Guard,

```
@Injectable()
export class HomePageRedirect implements CanActivate {
    canActivate() {
        //Your redirect logic
    
    if (this.user && this.user.lang) {
     this.router.navigate([this.user.lang,"home"]);
    }
    return true;
}
//Constructor 
constructor(private router: Router) { }
}
```

In your routes,

```
  { path: '' pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[HomePageRedirect] },
```